# concatenate corresponding elements from different list into one list

Tags: python

I know there is a bunch of similar answers here but I tried at least 10 of them and did not work in my case since it also involves splitting the list and adding string...so any help is appreciated!

Write   a   function    'conjunctions'  which   recevies    a   nested  list    'word_list'.    This    list    contains    a   number  of  sublists,   each    a   list    of  words   (i.e.   strings),   such    as:

```
[["Tom", "Laurel", "Merkel"], ["Jerry","Hardy", "Macron"]]
```

Note    that    all the sublists    have    the same    number  of  words   in  them.   Your    function    must    return  a   list    of  strings,    where   each    element in  a   position    is  an  "and"   conjunction of
all the elements    in  the same    position    in  all the sublists.   For example:

```
conjunctions([["Tom", "Laurel", "Merkel"],["Jerry","Hardy", "Macron"]])
```

should  return

```
['Tom and Jerry', 'Laurel and Hardy', 'Merkel and Macron']
```

and

```
conjunctions([["one", "apples"],["two","oranges"],["three","bananas"]])
```

should  return:

```
['one and two and three', 'apples and oranges and bananas']
```

I spent hours but all I can do is to change the order of the elements but I don't know how to further concatenate them:

```
def conjunctions(word_list):
    name = []
    for word in word_list:
        for length in range(len(word)):
            for n in range(len(word_list)):
                name.append(word_list[n][length])
        return name
```

this will only return me a list like this (using example two):

```
['one', 'two', 'three', 'apples', 'oranges', 'bananas']
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Sounds like you need `zip`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `zip` and join the strings putting `' and '` in between them.

```
>>> x = [["Tom", "Laurel", "Merkel"], ["Jerry","Hardy", "Macron"]]
>>> y = [["one", "apples"],["two","oranges"],["three","bananas"]]
>>> def conjunctions(L):
...     return [' and '.join(p) for p in zip(*L)]
... 
>>> conjunctions(x)
['Tom and Jerry', 'Laurel and Hardy', 'Merkel and Macron']
>>> conjunctions(y)
['one and two and three', 'apples and oranges and bananas']
```

Using zip with the asterisk, means that the list is converted to a set of arguments to the function (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2921847/what-does-the-star-operator-mean)) e.g. `zip(*[[1,2], [3,4]])` becomes `zip([1,2], [3,4])`. You can think of it as stripping the outermost list.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do so is to use `zip`

```
names = [["Tom", "Laurel", "Merkel"], ["Jerry","Hardy", "Macron"]]
[' and '.join(e) for e in zip(*names)]
```

This will print:

```
['Tom and Jerry', 'Laurel and Hardy', 'Merkel and Macron']
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this on both of your example lists and it works:

```
def conjunctions(l):
    tmp=[]
    for l2 in range(len(l[0])):
        tmp.append(' and '.join([l1[l2] for l1 in l]))
    return tmp
```

using zip seems simpler though